# How to use Python in Emacs (first time)

Tags: python, emacs, melpa

When I do `M-x` and `run-python` in Emacs, it gives me the following message: "Searching for program: No such file or directory, python3". I've gone through the steps of configuring the .emacs file as such:

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)

(defvar myPackages
  '(better-defaults                
    material-theme))

(defvar myPackages
 '(elpy))

(elpy-enable)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

Can someone please help me configure my emacs so I can use python in it?

Comment: Do you have a `python3` in your PATH? What does `which python3` tell you?

Comment: @NickD how can i check the PATH to see if python3 is in it?

Comment: Open a terminal and say `which python3` on the command line.